# Groupby - .agg function in Panda

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to write a code that groups the unique values on the first 3 fields below, then returns the count of price in one column and the sum of price in another column. I can't figure out why I am getting an "invalid syntax" error

```html
most_populat_item = pd.DataFrame(Heroes_file.groupby(["Item ID", "Item Name","Price"]).agg({"Price": ['sum','count']})
```

Comment: You dont need the `pd.DataFrame` constructor. If you want to, you are missing a bracket in the end. Lastly remove the () on the functions: `Heroes_file.groupby(["Item ID", "Item Name","Price"]).agg({"Price": ['sum','count']})`

Comment: I don't think you want to groupby on `Price` as well, you probably want: `Heroes_file.groupby(["Item ID", "Item Name"]).agg({"Price": ['sum','count']}`

Comment: your `agg` looks off. Maybe try `.agg(['sum', 'count'])`